# I'm going to write 'Unit of Work', please help me find out all gimmicks

Tags: design-patterns, unit-of-work

I'm going to write my own DAL in C#. I decided to use 'Unit of Work' pattern (next mentioned as uow) with request as a scope and Identity map stored in HttpContext.Items.

I have right now question about implementing of CRUD methods. How/where are they implemented? Are they implemented in every single business class (as in active records pattern) or are implemented somehow in uow class (if so, how)?

I also suppose that I need to use as the scope not just the request, but also the db connection. But how? Should I open the connection a the start of the request and close it on uow disposing?

Every advice is strongly appreciated, especially Your "real world" experiences.

Thank you all :)

Comment: Is the purpose of this an learning exercise or for a real-life, business scenario?  If it's for business, the best advice is not to roll your own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you're trying to develop your own [Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). I would say, don't try to go even near writing your own.

On-topic, one of the active contributers to the nHibernate ORM package, Davy Brion, has written a tutorial which includes how to write a simple ORM step-by-step.

He says that he's spend 24 hours writing the tutorial, so don't expect it to have anything near a production-ready ORM package.

Also, the tutorial is meant to explain how an ORM works, rather than actually motivating you to write a rival to the product nHibernate, the product he's contributing to.

[Build Your Own Data Access Layer Series](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/08/build-your-own-data-access-layer-series/)